# Phonegap Backbonejs works on simulator not device

Tags: ios, backbone.js, cordova, local-storage, cordova-3

**Using phonegap 3.1.0, Xcode 5.1.0, and iPad 2 with iOS 7.0.1**

I am writing a app for iPad and Im having some issues that seems very inconsistent in illogical.

1. The app works fine in the simulator
2. The app does not work on the device
3. The app starts working on the device once I remove the line ***localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage 'foo'***

This is the example Collection

```
class Channel extends Backbone.Model
    idAttribute: "ChannelID"
class Channels extends Backbone.Collection
    idAttribute:"ChannelID"
    initialize: =>
        @model = Channel
    localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage 'fc.channels'
```

As soon as I remove the localStorage line, it works. this happens only on the device, it works as exspected in the simulator, its as if the device is slow or something and does not load everything, **allthough the deviceready is triggered**

console.log Backbone.LocalStorage does not return anything

**UPDATE:**

**I found that backbone.localStorage-min.js is not loaded on the device! WHY!!!** At least now I know why its not working, but why the file is not loaded who knows!

**UPDATE 2:**

**I got it working by changing the name of the  backbone.localStorage-min.js to something else like backbonelocalstorage.js
This is the most ridicules thing I have ever come across!**

Comment: Weird, once I face something similar when a file was not loading despite all was correctly linked and named. After spending a lot of time I realized that is was a permission issue (in mac, listed with ls -la command). Maybe once you rename the file you change the permissions to the proper ones to be read by the system and project.

Comment: Good advice, thanks! I will keep it in mind